How to implement SDP(Scalable DP) on android
I want to implement sdp from here and it says I need to add implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.1' to my build.gradle dependencies block.
for example;
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.1'
}

If I directly copy the text, I got the following errors;

<html>Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:<br/>public inline operator fun BigDecimal.unaryMinus(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin<br/>public inline operator fun BigInteger.unaryMinus(): BigInteger defined in kotlin

Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)


So I tried to change it to this;
dependencies {
  implementation(com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.1)
}

But now I get these following errors;

Unresolved reference: intuit

Unexpected type specification

Expecting ','

<html>Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:<br/>public inline operator fun BigDecimal.unaryMinus(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin<br/>public inline operator fun BigInteger.unaryMinus(): BigInteger defined in kotlin

Expecting ')'

Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)


My original build.gradle.kts file;
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.appname"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.appname"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.navigation.ui)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
}

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? Do I need to download something or is the code just not compatible or something? Thanks in advance!

In which build.gradle file did you add this to? Adding it to the application level build.gradle has resolved with no errors when I tried it.

the app's build.gradle.kts (my build configuration language is kotlin dsl)

Care to add your build.gradle  file?

i added the file!

I just created a new empty project, migrated the build.gradle files to Kotlin DSL and added the intuit dependency. The project ran with no issues. Would you like me to post the build.gradle.kts as an answer?

That would be very helpful, thank you.

If my answer helps you, please accept and upvote it.

Following my comments, below is the build.gradle.kts with the sdp dependency. Although it doesn't have the other libraries you are relying on, it managed to compile and run without any issues.
app level build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.1")  /// <--- HERE
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
}

project level build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.3" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.3" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.20" apply false
}

I am using Android Studio Giraffe Patch 3
